# bad GNU libc argp code

Tags: parsing, linux, c++17

In [helpcovid](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid) git [commit `e27dd3b123c18300665`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/commit/e27dd3b123c183006654f81dca3b4a19cb9de95e) we have a stupid bug related to Linux GNU [glibc `argp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) program argument parsing.

```
void
hcv_parse_program_arguments(int &argc, char**argv)
{
  struct argp_state argstate;
  memset (&argstate, 0, sizeof(argstate));
  argstate.input = &hcv_progargs;
  hcv_progargs.hcv_progmagic = HCV_PROGARG_MAGIC;
  static struct argp argparser;
  argparser.options = hcv_progoptions;
  argparser.parser = hcv_parse1opt;
  argparser.args_doc = "*no-positional-arguments*";
  argparser.doc = "github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid"
                  " - a GPLv3+ free software to help organizing"
                  " against Covid19 - NO WARRANTY";
  argparser.children = nullptr;
  argparser.help_filter = nullptr;
  argparser.argp_domain = nullptr;
  if (argp_parse(&argparser, argc, argv, 0, nullptr, nullptr))
    HCV_FATALOUT("failed to parse program arguments to " << argv[0]);
#warning TODO: complete hcv_parse_program_arguments
} // end hcv_parse_program_arguments
```

The bug is obvious, but I cannot find it.

At runtime, with the `main`  function being:

```
int
main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  hcv_early_initialize(argv[0]);
  hcv_parse_program_arguments(argc, argv);
  HCV_SYSLOGOUT(LOG_NOTICE, "start of " << argv[0] << std::endl
                <<  " version:" << hcv_versionmsg);
  HCV_SYSLOGOUT(LOG_INFO, "normal end of " << argv[0]);
  return 0;
} // end of main
```

we observe immediately:

```
rimski.x86_64 ~/helpcovid 19:12 .0 % ./helpcovid 
** HELPCOVID FATAL! hcv_main.cc:84:: corrupted program arguments
**** FATAL ERROR hcv_main.cc:84
./helpcovid[3684197]: FATAL STOP hcv_main.cc:84 (Success)
zsh: abort (core dumped)  ./helpcovid
```

happening in

```
// parse a single program option
static error_t
hcv_parse1opt (int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state)
{
  /* Get the input argument from argp_parse, which we
     know is a pointer to our arguments structure. */
  struct hcv_progarguments *progargs
    = reinterpret_cast<hcv_progarguments *>(state->input);
  if (!progargs || progargs->hcv_progmagic != HCV_PROGARG_MAGIC)
    // this should never happen
    HCV_FATALOUT("corrupted program arguments"); //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  switch (key)
    {
    default:
      return ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN;
    }
} // end hcv_parse1opt
```

The error being at line with `//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@`, [file `hcv_main.cc` line 84](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/blob/master/hcv_main.cc#L84). The `gdb` debugger tells that `progargs` is a null pointer (and should not be).

Comment: Can you please edit the post to share some more details about the bug? Such as the expected behavior vs the observed behavior.

Comment: Isn't code on this site supposed to be bug free? From a meta question tagged as an FAQ, *"[A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777)"* (my emphasis): *"Please, we **don't want** the following kinds of questions ... questions where the code **does not work as intended**"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the call to `argp_parse()` in `hcv_parse_program_arguments()` is missing a pointer to the arguments struct. Looking at the `main()` function in the canonical [Argp Example 3](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp-Example-3.html), we see that the `argp_parse()` function is passed a pointer to `struct arguments arguments`.

```
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct arguments arguments;

  /* Default values. */
  arguments.silent = 0;
  arguments.verbose = 0;
  arguments.output_file = "-";

  /* Parse our arguments; every option seen by parse_opt will
     be reflected in arguments. */
  argp_parse (&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &arguments);

  printf ("ARG1 = %s\nARG2 = %s\nOUTPUT_FILE = %s\n"
          "VERBOSE = %s\nSILENT = %s\n",
          arguments.args[0], arguments.args[1],
          arguments.output_file,
          arguments.verbose ? "yes" : "no",
          arguments.silent ? "yes" : "no");

  exit (0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please note, questions involving code that's not working as intended, are off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.